# UML ассоциация

Tags: uml

Разобрался с агрегацией и композицией, собственно что такое асоциация тоже понятно. Не понятно как реализовать ассоциацию? К примеру, если композиция значит создаем экземпляр внтури класса

`class CompositeCustomService
{
    // Композиция
    private readonly CustomRepository _repository
          = new CustomRepository();
    public void DoSomething()
    { 
        // Используем _repository
    }
}`

а если агрегация то передаем как параметр

```
    class AggregatedCustomService
{ 
    // Агрегация
    private readonly AbstractRepository _repository; 
    public AggregatedCustomService(AbstractRepository repository) 
    { 
        _repository = repository; 
    } 
    public void DoSomething() 
    { 
        // Используем _repository
    }
}
```

А если простая ассоция между двумя классами как это реализуется?

Answer (score 2):

Если мне не изменяет память, то ассоциация - это просто использование экземпляра другого класса. Например `Foo -> Bar` выглядит как-то так:

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar Property { get; set; }
    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello " + Property.Name);
    }

}

class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```